# Differentiation (as a linear map) maps what to what?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In multivariable calculus, the derivative of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ at some point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the unique linear map $\left. Df \right|_p$ such that
$$ f(p+h) = f(p) + \left. Df \right|_p (h) + \varepsilon(h) \lVert h \rVert,$$
where $\varepsilon(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

If we define $f$ only for some proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the derivative maps which space to which space? It can't be from the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $f$ is no longer defined everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will indeed be the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ since we don't care about where $f$ takes values. We just need a linear map. A linear map has to be defined on a vector space, thus we chose $\mathbb{R}^n$. In reality it is true that for the definition of the derivative, we will only be looking at very small values of $h$ but this is of no concern to us.

Answer (score 1):

The linear map $Df|_p$ is a matrix. You don't need *f* to be defined everywhere in order for $Df|_p$ to be defined everywhere.  Think about the $1$-dimensional case. If $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and we set $m = f'(1/3)$, which is a number, do you think $x \mapsto mx$ can't be defined on all of $\mathbf R$?

A matrix is completely determined by its behavior in any small ball, so consider the fact that the matrix can be applied far from $p$ to be a bit irrelevant.